# What is the bottom space on the Windows Forms design view?

Tags: c#, winforms, designview

I'm trying to learn about Windows Forms Application. Now, as I was creating a DataSet, Binding source, Table adapters. I noticed they show up on a bottom section on the design view. My question is: What is that section, and what goes in there?

Comment: Its a "tray" for non-visible components you add to your form through the design view.

Comment: As others have said, it's just a section for objects on the form that don't have a visual component. I recently was assigned the task of converting some old Borland C++ application to C#.NET and I can tell you it's pretty damn nice *not* having your form designer covered in DataSets and crap like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This section generally corresponds to nonvisual elements in a Form, but which are stil relevant to the Form, such as a Timer.

Since they're nonvisual, it doesn't make sense to put them in the designer with the visual elements, but they still need to be in the designer for the designer to be useful in setting their values.

Answer (score 5):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e06hs424(v=vs.100).aspx):

> Non-visual components added to the Windows Forms Designer are placed on the **Component Tray**, located below the design surface, so that they are easily accessible without cluttering the visual design space.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom part of the winforms designer is used for non-UI elements. Things that are created / generated just as fields in the class behind, and not added to the actual view.