# Invisible timer control in Windows Forms project designer view

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, timer

I drag a timer control to a form in a Windows Forms project in Visual Studio 2022. The control exists, I see it in the Properties window, but not in the pane below the graphical editor.
What could be the problem?
[image]

Comment: You don't see it because it's not an actual timer but a timer control.

Comment: I Know that, but it's should be seen in The Pane under the Graphic Designer.

Comment: See this, it's only for non-visual components: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31679270/361899

Comment: It's a Component not a Control. In the components Window, right click -> Line Up Icons. Still can't see them? Close the designer, clean and rebuild, open the designer.

Comment: Normally the non-visual component is visible only in pane under the Graphic Designer, not in the form itself.
The issue is that he is invisible in that pane.

Answer (score 1):

dr.null solved the issue [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76826813/invisible-timer-control-in-windows-forms-project-designer-view/76827922#comment135441310_76826813):

> It's a Component not a Control. In the components Window, right click -> Line Up Icons. Still can't see them? Close the designer, clean and rebuild, open the designer.